# how create TCP server by ESP8266?

Tags: arduino, tcpserver, esp8266

I want to create a simple Wifi TCP server by ESP8266 in Arduino IDE. But I have a big problem: when I send a character or string from client I can't receive it on the server.

In fact I connect esp8266  to my PC and I want to see send character from client in pc terminal.
 my sending side is Socket protocol app for android!and complete code I write in sever side is:

```
WiFiServer server(8888);
void setup() 
{
  initHardware();
  setupWiFi();
  server.begin();
}
void loop() 
{
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    if (client.available() > 0) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
    }
  }
}
void setupWiFi()
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP("RControl", WiFiAPPSK);
}

void initHardware()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
```

Baudrate it set to 115200 on both sides.

Comment: Please provide more code, seeing both sides will help.

Comment: @Marged: I'd assume that, too, but "doesn't receive" doesn't imply "but the program executes successfully on the sending side".

Comment: my sending side is SocketProtocol app when I click on send button thats status change to sending message!I think that cant send message!

Comment: Did you look to the [telnet sample](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/esp8266/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiTelnetToSerial/WiFiTelnetToSerial.ino) ?

Comment: wow!thanks very much mpromonet .that's work correctly!Its a useful link.

Comment: Non-blocking: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/40271/how-to-create-a-simple-tcp-server-with-the-analogread-value-on-wemos-d1-mini based on Telnet Sample here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiTelnetToSerial/WiFiTelnetToSerial.ino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the loop, you are closing the client connection as soon as it is established deleting the `WiFiClient` object.

In order to keep the connection open you could modify the loop like this :

```
WiFiClient client;
void loop() 
{
    if (!client.connected()) {
        // try to connect to a new client
        client = server.available();
    } else {
        // read data from the connected client
        if (client.available() > 0) {
            Serial.write(client.read());
        }
    }
}
```

When client is not connected it tries to connect one and when a client is connected, it reads incoming data.